# How do you get jquery $(this) to work in a function that has to have variables passed to it?

Tags: jquery

I'm pulling my hair out trying to do something which I think should be pretty easy. I appreciate any help!

I want to call a javascript function when a  is clicked, pass two variables to it, and then use jquery to hide that span. A simple example is

```
function myFunction(data1,data2) {
var data = data1+data2;
alert(data);
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).hide(); <---doesn't work
});
}

<span onClick="myFunction(1,3)">Click here to send 1, 3 and hide this span</span>
<span onClick="myFunction(8,9)">Click here to send 8, 9 and hide this span</span>
```

The variables (1,3) & (8,9) are loaded dynamically with a php script. Adding the two variables together isn't the intent of the script, but it seems the simplest way to explain what i'm after.

So how do you get `$(this)` to work in a function that has to have variables passed to it?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `.hide()` the `$(document)` instead of the span

Not really sure why you're putting it inside a doc ready statement... try it like this...

```
function myFunction(span,data1,data2) {
    var data = data1+data2;
    alert(data);
    $(span).hide();
}

<span onClick="myFunction(this,1,3)">Click here to send 1, 3 and hide this span</span>
<span onClick="myFunction(this,8,9)">Click here to send 8, 9 and hide this span</span>
```

Comment: Lol, and mine got upvoted. +1 for a virtually identical answer.

Answer (score 1):

Init your JS, then load the function. You shouldn't be nesting the `ready` function in there.

Also, you can pass `this` as a function parameter to reference the object which called the function, like so (also, `onClick` isn't valid. `onclick` is. Big difference, huh?):

```
function myFunction(that, data1,data2) {
  var data = data1+data2;
  alert(data);
  $(that).hide();  // Can't use this, so that will work.
}

<span onclick="myFunction(this, 1,3)">Click here to send 1, 3 and hide this span</span>
<span onclick="myFunction(this, 8,9)">Click here to send 8, 9 and hide this span</span>
```

Comment: did you literally just copy/paste my answer 2 minutes later?

Comment: No, I was working on it and then yours popped in. You edited too, I think. There aren't many other ways to do this, so don't think I copy/pasted your answer (why would anyone???).

Answer (score -1):

jondavidjohn is right. However, it's a bad practice to embed event handlers in html. This should be the way:

```
function myFunction(data1,data2) {
    var data = data1+data2;
    alert(data);
    $(this).hide();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#span1").click(function(){
     myFunction(1,3);
   });
   $("#span2").click(function(){
     myFunction(8,9);
   });
});
```

...

```
<span id="span1">Click here to send 1, 3 and hide this span</span>
<span id="span2">Click here to send 8, 9 and hide this span</span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: except that you are trying to `.hide()` the global window object, which will most definitely not work...  also, if you provide an answer like this, also include how he would inject the arguments of `myFunction()` with php...

Comment: Why is it bad practice, might I ask?

Comment: Quoted from the question... `"The variables (1,3) & (8,9) are loaded dynamically with a php script."`

Comment: jondavidjohn, you are wrong. When an event is binded with `bind`, (or in this case, `click`), the context is set to the "binded" element, so `this` references the span, not the window object.
If you still disagree, just try the code in your browser.

Comment: Blender, mixing html attributes and javascript is obtrusive, and it has been deprecated since DOM level 2. Writing unobtrusive code is a better practice (more mantainable, more separation, etc)
There's much information on the web, [here's one](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/best-practices-for-modern-javascript-development)

You can search about "unobtrusive javascript" for more information

Comment: jondavidjohn, want me to explain how to inject the arguments in php?
You just print a Json object using json_encode into the javascript.
Or (better), you can create (from php) two custom attributes for each span, named data-data1, and data-data2 (the "data-" prefix is to be HTML5 compliant), and pass them to the function using jquery's attr.